# How to invalidate session on JSP login page

Tags: java, jsp, session, jsessionid

I have a barebone login JSP page and after I launch the application for the first time (visiting http://localhost:8080/), a session is immediately created which I feel is a big security flaw in the application, In my web.xml code, I have set my  to be login.jsp, and in my loginServlet is when after posting your credentials in the login.jsp and everything checks out, is when a session will be created, honestly I don't understand why the session is being created and I will appreciate some clarification.

I am using a servlet filter to block access if the session is null and this is how I realized that there is a session created after loading the login page

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

//from loginServlet, will only execute after posting from login page
            System.out.println("login successful");
            if (context != null){
                //get the old session and invalidate
                HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession(false);
                if (oldSession != null) {
                    System.out.println("Session is not null");
                    oldSession.invalidate();
                }

                //generate a new session & set to expiry in 5 mins
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);
```

Comment: In the almost all circumstances there will be a session (some times it is a session per request). The session exists to retain a state between the client and server. generally the session is created in the container and injected into the request, so your 'request.getSession(false);' would return the session created by the container. to understand more try reading through: https://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-session-management-servlet-httpsession-url-rewriting

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why you think the creation of a session should be a _security flaw_. Session is just a container for whatever you put in it. Its sole existence does not mean that a user can do anything bad in your webapp, or is automatically logged in.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSP page the session are automatically created , the same question was asked in this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389947/how-the-session-is-automatically-created-in-my-jsp-page-if-i-have-not-created-se)

> in a JSP, a session is created (unless it already exists, obviously) as soon as you hit this JSP.
>
> Unless you use the directive
>       <%@ page session="false" %>

there is also this [post](https://www.careerride.com/JSP-Session.aspx) that explains some of what you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

```
<%session.invalidate();%>
<% HttpSession nsession = request.getSession(false);
if(nsession!=null) {
   String data=(String)session.getAttribute( "fname" );
   out.println(data);
}
else
  out.println("Session is not active");
%>
Output:
while opening display page, all the attributes are getting displayed on client (browser).
Since we have already called invalidate in the first line of errorpage.jsp, it is displaying the message “Session is not active” on the screen

Points to Note:
1) This will deactivate the session

<%session.invalidate();%>
2) This logic will exceute the if body when the session is active else it would run the else part.

<% HttpSession nsession = request.getSession(false);
if(nsession!=null)
   ...
else
   ...
%>
```